# For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, evaluate $\int_0^n \cos(2\pi \lfloor x\rfloor\{x\})dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

Can anyone please evaluate and explain this integral? Here $n$ is a positive integer.

$$\int_0^n \cos(2 \pi \lfloor x\rfloor \{x\}) dx$$

Comment: See also: [Definite integral involving floor and fractional part](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1989492).