# How to evaluate $ \int_0^n \cos(2\pi \lfloor x\rfloor\{x\})dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

For a real number $ x$, let $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denote the largest integer less than or equal to $x$ and $ \{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ (floor and fractional part, resepectively). Let $n$ be a positive integer. I want to evaluate$$ \int_0^n \cos(2\pi \lfloor x\rfloor\{x\})dx$$

I broke down the integral as
$$\int_0^1\cos(2\pi \cdot 0 \cdot x)dx+\int_1^2\cos(2\pi \cdot 1 \cdot x)dx +\cdots+ \int_{n-1}^{n}\cos(2\pi \cdot (n-1)\cdot x)dx$$

However I got the wrong answer and I couldn’t understand where I went wrong.

Comment: In the integrals you got (x) wrong: in the second integral you should write (x-1),  in the last (x-n+1)

Comment: @Luca but I have also changed the limits.if x would have been what you have told in the second integral then limit must be then 1 to 2.did you get what I mean?

Comment: You are right, I didn't see it. So, now, you are saying that $1$ is not the right answer?

Comment: @Luca yes exactly the answer is given out to be n

Comment: Your book it's mistaken

Comment: Maybe you (or the book) missed a module sign?

Comment: @Luca  how would a module sign(where) affect the answer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47612/discussion-between-luca-and-navinstudent).

Comment: @Luca I am using mobile app right now.can you please a bit explain what I pointed out earlier.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your book: take $n=2$: the second integral is zero. If there was a module, it would be positive, but not equal to 1, but to $\frac{2}{\pi}$. So, your book is wrong. Or we are dunces. But I have a PhD in Maths, so...

Comment: @Luca I respect you sir/mam but in my view the second integral is zero for all n.where you are pointing out a module to  be missing out?how did you arrived st $2/\pi$?

Comment: Just saying, if it was $\int_0^1 |cos(2\pi x)|dx$ it would not be $0$, but then I did the integral and it is  $\int_0^1 |cos(2\pi x)|dx = \frac{2}{\pi}$. When you integrate a factor $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ pops out, so it has to be wrong.

Comment: Goodnight sir/madam, it's night in Italy

Comment: @Luca yes I got it.thanks the book must be wrong and a module sign would have made the question more lively.....thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The interval $[0,1]$ brings a contribution $$\int_0^1dx=1$$ while all others integrate the cosine over an integer number of periods !

Answer (score 3):

Here are some hints only, since you did not provide any effort:

I assume that $n$ is a positive integer. I suggest that you divide your integral as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{k-1}^k\cos\bigl(2\pi[x](x-[x])\bigr)\,dx.
$$
Then use that, in the integral from $k-1$ to $k$, $[x]=k-1$. Insert this. Then, use the periodicity of cosine, and you will find that only one of the integrals (for what $k$?) is non-zero. A very simple calculation shows that the non-zero integral equals $1$.

For this question, a graph could be useful. The case $n=5$ is attached below.

[image]

Comment: I understood that integral 0 to 1 is 1. but how other integrals are zero?please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Here is to complete the ideas of the OP. I am surprised there are not many answers to this relatively old question.

Splitting the interval $[0,n]$ as $[0,n]=[0,1]\cup(1,2]\cup\ldots\cup(n-1,n]$ as the OP does the trick.

The first term in the OP's splitting
$$\int_0^1\cos(2\pi \cdot 0\cdot x)dx+\int_1^2\cos(2\pi x)dx +\cdots+ \int_{n-1}^{n}\cos(2\pi (n-1)\cdot x)dx$$

is $\int^1_0\,dt=1$. Each of the remaining terms is $0$

$$
\int^{k+1}_k\cos(2\pi k x)\,dx =\frac{1}{2\pi k}\sin(2\pi k x)\big|^{k+1}_k=0
$$